# C++ Heap destructor when data types are implicitly stored

Tags: c++, pointers, heap-memory, destructor

Quick question,

I'm new to C++ and I'm having difficulty understanding the destructors.

I'll explain; lets say we have the following;

```
int _a;

a::a(int x) {

    _a = x 
}
```

then we have

```
a* a1 = new a(8);
```

I understand that a1's data is created on the heap, and a1 is a pointer, where I'm failing is with the destructor;

```
a::~a() {

    // confusion here
}
```

Since _a is not a pointer since it was created implicitly on the heap thanks to new (correct) we cannot delete it so what do we do?

Does

```
delete a1;
```

call the destructor for a int automatically?

Comment: Do not that you should not use leading underscores for names in your code.  There are certain cases where they are reserved for the implementation so it is best just to avoid the situation entirely.

Comment: what is `_a`? And what makes you believe it was created on the heap?

Comment: Also why do you think you would need to call a destructor for an `int` (or any other "normal" data type) and what would that destructor do?

Comment: @UnholySheep lets say _a is a custom class. Doesn't keyword new mean it's heap created?

Comment: I don't see a's definition, _x is not used anywhere... I am assuming that _x is supposed to be _a as a member of class a? It so, please specify this.

Comment: @ThomasLötzer thanks, missed that edit. _x IS meant to be _a

Comment: @Lloyd.S You missed many things to provide a [MCVE] as it is required for asking at Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1):

I understand what you're driving at and the answer is **no, C++ destructors do not automatically destroy the data that your class contains**. Unfortunately your example is too contrived to highlight the problem well. `int` is a primitive type so its destruction is primitive (someone might want to comment on what *actually* happens in `int`s destructor). Take the following example:

```
class A
{
    public:
    int x;
    ~A()
    {
        std::out << "in A destructor" << std::endl;
    }
};

class B
{
    public:
    A* x;

    B()
    {
        x = new A();
    }

    ~B()
    {
        std::out << "in B destructor" << std::endl;
        // does not automatically delete x
    }
};

auto x = new B();
delete x;
```

In this example, constructing an instance of `B` will also construct an instance of `A` because you explicitly new it up in the constructor of `B`. However, unless you explicitly `delete` `x` in your destructor for `B` it will not automatically be deleted.

A slight variation of me previous example would be if `B::x` were of type `A` and not `A*`, in which case the answer is **yes, the destructor for A would be called**.

I hope this helps!

Comment: `auto x = new B();
delete x;`

Comment: my bad not use to stackoverflow let me try again

Comment: so say if we had `auto x = new A(); delete x;` we don't need anything in A's destructor since it will call ints destructor?

Answer (score 1):

> call the destructor for a int automatically?

That would be true if the object were a class type. For non-class types, there is no destrutor, not even implicitly defined ones. Hence, the question of calling the destructor does not arise.

Had your code been something like:

```
struct Foo
{
   Foo() {}
   ~Foo() {}
};

struct a
{
   Foo f
};

a* aptr = new a;
delete aptr;
```

The destructor, `Foo::~Foo()`, will be called for `f`.

Answer (score 1):

The destructor is just a function that is called automatically when the instance comes out of scope. It's a convenient way to release dynamically allocated memory.

You don't have to worry about releasing variables that were allocated on the stack (anything that is declared and not **new**-ed).

For example:

```
int localStackVar = 5; //no need to deallocate explicitly
int* localPointer = &localStackVar // no need to deallocate explicitly
int* heapValue = new int(); //Allocates to the heap so you need to call delete explicitly
```

The first two from the example above are on the stack, the first one is an int and the second is an int pointer, which is just a way to say it's a variable that holds the memory address of another variable.
Both of those will be deallocated automatically, since you did not call `new` on them.

The third line allocates an int on the heap. You have to call `delete` on it when you don't need it anymore.

If those 3 variables were a part of a class, your constructor and destructors would look like this:

```
MyClass::MyClass()
{
   heapValue = new int();
}

MyClass::~MyClass() //destructor
{
   delete heapValue;
}

void someFun()
{
   MyClass instance; //constructor is called here 
   //do stuff
   return; //destructor is called here
}
```

So while `MyClass instance` is a local stack variable when declared in `someFun`
since the constructor is called automatically, heapVal is made to point to a memory location that is on the heap which needs to be released explicitly.

If your destructor did not call delete on it, the memory would "leak" it will not be released until your program terminates.